# How to generate the correct ActionLink for custom Routing attribute

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.actionlink, attributerouting

My controller is using routing attribute as follow

### Controller

```
[Route("tenant/{tenantId}/store/edit/{id}")]
public ActionResult Edit(int tenantId, int id)
{
    ...
}
```

### View

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Store", new { tenantId = Request.QueryString["tenantId"], id = item.Id}, null)
```

I'm expecting the URL to generated by ActionLink to look like `http://localhost/tenant/1/store/edit/3` but it's generating something like `http://localhost/store/edit/3?tenantId=1` instead

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, as i already edited the previous from from "tenant" controller, i was no longer using querystring to get the tenantId.

Instead now i'm using

```
var tId = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["tenantId"];
```

and the updated ActionLink should look something like this

```
Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Store", new { tenantId = tId, id = item.Id}, null)
```